# how to disable all listbox in a form

Tags: javascript

how to disable all listbox  in a form

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#formId select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Edit: oops, thought I saw a jquery tag. Anyway:-

```
for (i = 0; i < theform.length; i++) {
        var formElement = theform.elements[i];
        if (formElement.tagName === "SELECT") {
            formElement.disabled = true;
        }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't that comparison against the tag name be against uppercase 'SELECT'? or be all converted to lower case... if(formElement.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'select'){...

Comment: you're right of course, though I'd probably prefer Marius's answer entirely. damn frameworks turning the brain to mush!

Answer (score 3):

Just to improve on Gavin's correct answer:

```
var selects = theform.getElementsByTagName("select");
for (i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
  selects[i].disabled = true;
}
```